# Isolate Local Machines From One Another To Increase Security

Tags: windows

Allow me to lay a foundation for the question.

I am not an expert in regard to servers or SysAdmin things, but we were recently hit with a wave of the Emotet virus on my company's network.

After studying the virus for a few days I was able to find out how it works and remove it from the machines on our network.

A key takeaways with the virus is that it wormed it's way through the network machine to machine. If you remove it from one machine that is still connected to the network, another machine that is infected will re-infect the clean machine.

Now for the question.

Is the following set of procedures a valid way to prevent a virus like this from spreading across the *entire* network?

If so, what negative outcomes could be foreseen by updating our network settings as follows?

---

*Local White listed IP's are for server and printers*

*Non-Local White listed IP's are for things like microsoft.com*

1:)Block outbound connections on all PC's for every local IP except white listed ones.

(Virus jumps from computer to computer)

2:)Block inbound connections on all PC's from every local IP except white listed ones.

(Virus jumps from computer to computer)

3:)Block outbound connections from server to every local IP except white listed ones.

(Virus jumps from server to computer)

(This isolates the virus on the host computer and the servers.)

4:)Block outbound connections from server to every non-local IP except white listed ones.

(Virus cant talk to cnc server, but also loses internet capability)

5:)Block inbound connections from non-local IP except white listed ones to server.

(Virus can't talk to cnc server)

To my (albeit limited) understanding, this setup will allow a virus like this to spread from a computer to the server, and only the server rather than every machine in the network.

I understand that this doesn't *prevent* the virus, but rather alleviates the damage done by it.

Answer (score 3):

Forget all of this craziness and do the correct thing:

1. Do not give Administrator rights to users.
2. Keep UAC enabled.
3. Put in a firewall with a web content filter.
4. Keep up to date with Windows Updates.
5. Use Group Policy to disable macros in Office, or only allow signed macros.
6. Install proper antivirus/antimalware software on all computers.

Comment: 6. Install proper antivirus/antimalware software on all computers.

Comment: @joeqwerty this slipped past a fully updated malwarebytes.

Answer (score 1):

In this day and age where many useful services rely on cloud providers and CDN's  white-listing ip-addresses  is a complete nightmare.

I *think* that in general maintaining host based firewalls is a PITA when you'd have to so at enterprise scale, but I have never tried to do so...

Most organisations do indeed some of what you propose by means of [network zoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_segmentation) with firewalls securing access to and from each network segment.

Also very common is that direct internet access is severely restricted or simply denied outright and users and applications are required to use proxy servers.  It is much easier to white-list domains and URL's on a proxy server than it is to maintain IP-address white-lists.

Comment: Is there a pretty industry standard way of network zoning? Like a specific tool that is used?

Comment: It is not so much tools as it is a network design philosophy where one classifies and groups systems based on purpose, location and risk assessment. Similar systems then go into the same network segment secured from other network segments. Each network can be physically separate or logically separated by means of VLAN's for instance. The most basic and common network zones that most people will recognise are an DMZ and a trusted LAN

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes these measures can be heavy handed and make using the network difficult for employees.  They can't get work done because internet access is blocked, which in turn means that the company has invested in assets that no longer provide productivity improvements.  Going back to pencil and paper will solve the risk of being infected by viruses but you loose the benefits provided by technology.

As a result, you need to come up with a strategy to ensure you can handle whatever is thrown at you without making too much work for yourself in terms of managing access and impacting productivity.

### 1. Assume you will be hacked.

Nation states have been stockpiling "zero day exploits" so that when the day comes, they can get into your system if they want.  Antivirus software will not stop these.  They may not do anything (just collect and exfiltrate information), they may alter specific key values, or they might just cause a lot of damage (e.g. if your company was centrifuging uranium, you might find the centrifuges kept breaking down beyond repair for some strange reason...).

As a result, backups will be your friend.  Be in a position where you can restore a given system (or all systems) within a short period of time and operate them in isolation (to avoid reinfection) until the source is determined.

Also, keep some usable backups offline.  Some ransomware specifically targets reachable backups, so you have to be prepared for that scenario.

### 2. Maintain Up-to-date Systems

"Zero-day exploits" are valuable, and if they are observed and the holes in the software identified, they can be patched.  As a result, bad actors only use them when they have to as their usefulness is potentially limited.
So they will typically start with more well-known exploits.  The simplest counter-measure to this is ensuring that all the software is the latest version.

There is a downside to this - which is that software makers often charge fees to give their customers the latest version, so it can be tempting not to update.  They may also discontinue support for versions in use, so that you upgrade to the next (more expensive) major release.

Some work arounds are to keep legacy software operating on hardened machines, so that their security flaws are not exploited.  Most of the time, these flaws do not result in usable exploits anyway.

You have to use your judgement to determine the best trade off (or give management the information to make that decision).

### 3. Maintain and Anti-virus Procedure

Even if it is just running a rescue CD periodically, it is important to ensure that you do pick up malware that is around.  Up-to-date on access scanners should help, along with periodic scans.  If the software interferes with daily work too much or becomes an annoyance, switch to another product.

### 4. Minimize Methods and Scope of Attack

Be aware of the most common ways malware can get in (email attachments, malicious web sites, USB sticks found in the parking lot, script kiddies trying to SSH into your network from China) and look at how that malware could spread from those hosts to the rest of the network.  Don't use CNC machines for reading email and viewing attachments - keep them on a separate network, and limit the protocols that traverse the networks to only the ones that are needed using access lists or a firewall.

While whitelisting is a commendable method to limit scope, it is often administratively unworkable (too much work for too little gain).  Protocol level rather than host or domain-level restrictions may be easier to implement.  Make a list of which methods will be the easiest to manage, have the least impact on users and provide the greatest benefit.  If time permits, work further down the list.

Comment: In your opinion would blocking all intra-network communications that aren't required be a bad idea? Two machines are allowed to talk to a server, but not to each other. And the server allowed to talk back but not initiate the conversation.

Comment: IMHO that would be a little too granular.  If the server communicates on tcp port 5000 to the machines, put an access list on the router acting as gateway to the subnet of just the machines to permit only port 5000 traffic.  To know for sure, I'd need to know what protocols are used by the machines.  If the machines have USB drives that people use - perhaps put each machine on a separate VLAN with the same rule.. it depends on the situation